# how to control the usage of each GPU used on each machine in k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Ask a question, how to control the usage of each GPU used on each machine in k8s cluster of two machines with two graphics cards on each machine. Now each card has 15g. I want to use 10g + for the other three cards, leaving 7g + free for one graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how graphics cards work. the GPU RAM is physically part of the graphics card and is exclusive to that GPU.